# windows phone 8 cordova viewport height issue

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova, updates

we Developed a windows phone 8 app with cordova.
Its working proerly but after the windows phone8 **8.0.10328.78** release the footer is get disrub.
I Checked into the code earlier i am getting the height of viewport as 768 and now its 800.

what will be solution here.

Comment: Just to clearify:  for you the footer is also partly out of view,  like the actual viewport is bigger than the screen?     And changing stuff to the  @-ms-viewport fix (that was probably already included)  doesn't change the behaviour at all any more?   (At least, that is what I'm experiencing after updating WP8 for a perfectly ok looking app)

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution for this

In `MainPage.xaml` change

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
```

to

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recently run into this issue building a page to run within the WebView. The issue is the viewport height... Using "height=device-height" makes the viewport the entire screen height (less the app tray).

The fix I used was to declare an initial value in the height of 460, and then dynamically replace that value once the document has loaded. This technique works across all devices (that I've tested), including Windows, Android and iOS.

With the example below remember not to move the viewport meta tag from it's current position, the JS targets the second meta tag in the head, if you move it, you'll need to update the JS accordingly.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=460">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    ...
</head>

<body>
    ...
    <script>
        (function() {
            'use strict';

            var fixHeight = function() {
                var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
                var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;

                var viewportContent = 'initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=' + viewportHeight;
                document.getElementsByTagName('META')[1].content = viewportContent;
            };

            window.addEventListener('load', fixHeight);
            window.addEventListener('resize', fixHeight);
         })();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in your CSS:

```
@-ms-viewport{
    width: device-width;
    height: device-height;
}
```

Comment: Here that doesn't work,  adding height:device-height;  just makes the app zoom out more, but the footer still goes out of view partially.